# TSQL How get total percentage for group by months

Tags: t-sql, aggregate

I have the below query which return me the percentage of job printed at the different print sites based on a date range:

```
SELECT 
 DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime) as Year
,MAX(DATENAME(MONTH, ReceivingTime)) as Month
,ProductionLocation 
,CAST( count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)  )over() as decimal(10,2) ) AS Totals FROM Jobs_analytics

WHERE ProductionLocation IS NOT NULL AND ReceivingTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2019-08-25'
GROUP BY  DATENAME(YEAR,ReceivingTime), DATEPART(MONTH, ReceivingTime), ProductionLocation 
 ORDER BY DATENAME(YEAR, ReceivingTime),  DATEPART(MONTH,  ReceivingTime)
```

Which works and I get the following results:

[image]

Whats happening is my query is breaking down the whole date range.

What I was looking for is the months of January for example:

> If I added the totals up I want 100% not the percentage break down for
>   the entire date range.

Not sure if I explain this correctly.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extremely close I think.

You already have an `OVER()` clause, but you left it empty, if you replace `OVER()` with `OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, ReceivingTime))` then it should give you what you want?

Here's a simpler example for you:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE ([month] INT, production_location VARCHAR(50), something INT);
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'Toronto', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'Toronto', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'Woodlands', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'Woodlands', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 1, 'Woodlands', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 2, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 2, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 2, 'BOND', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 2, 'Woodlands', 1;
INSERT INTO @x SELECT 2, 'Woodlands', 1;

--Empty OVER() clause
SELECT
    [month],
    production_location,
    COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS total
FROM
    @x
GROUP BY
    [month],
    production_location
ORDER BY
    1, 2;

--PARTITION BY month
SELECT
    [month],
    production_location,
    COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY [month]) AS total
FROM
    @x
GROUP BY
    [month],
    production_location
ORDER BY
    1, 2;
```

Results are:

```
month   production_location total
1   BOND        23.076923076923
1   Toronto     15.384615384615
1   Woodlands   23.076923076923
2   BOND        23.076923076923
2   Woodlands   15.384615384615
```

versus:

```
month   production_location total
1   BOND        37.500000000000
1   Toronto     25.000000000000
1   Woodlands   37.500000000000
2   BOND        60.000000000000
2   Woodlands   40.000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you added the year to the partition and worked like a charm!